# Send email with attachment using Email Task URL hack

Tags: email

```
'/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid=' + caseId + '&doc_id=' + docId + '&retURL=' + caseId + '';
```

I'm using the above URL to send an email with attachment in the doc_id parameter I'm sending the ID of the file to be attached but it is not attaching the file in the task. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can I ask why are you doing this? What is the business case? How do you even get the docID?

Comment: Umm, I just wanted to create a button which would land you to the email task activity page and attach the pdf file which you just generated. 
Anyways you cannot give the attachment id as document id so the workaround for that was to store it in documents and give the actual document id in the url param!
cheers!

Answer (score 1):

the solution is very simple - you should clone the email template and associate the attachment to it.
then use the clone emailtemplate in the URL redirect.
and don't forget to add to the URL - +'&new_template=1'
otherwise, it will not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that's why I asked what is the business case for doing this. I have a client wanting to do something very similar at the moment. The approach I have suggested is to use Drawloop as it has a great UI to select the email template, select the contact and select create the document and send it (you can even add other attachments that are already on the record). And you can create a button or even trigger this sending of the email via an outbound message. All this for starting at $12/month/user, is good value. (disclaimer, I am a Drawloop Partner, but I do think this is a great product and a good, non code, solution for this business case, and once you get it in there for one business case, it can be used for so much more).